# Is there a way to prepend to every email in Linux?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I want to set up my SMTP server so that every email I send has the same tag [TAG]at the beginning of the subject. Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using postfix header checks.

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre

#/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre
/^Subject: (.+)$/    REPLACE Subject: [TAG] $1
```

See [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) for more info. Hope that helps.